# Q&A approach vs Term&Definition approach for e-learning application

Tags: sql

I am in the process of creating an e-learning application that will be based on a system of questions and answers, and the creation of exercises and exams by the user, whether the teacher or the student himself. When designing the database, an issue appeared that confused me. My thought at first, as is normal for most educational applications, was to design a table for the questions and a separate other table for answers are as follows:

```
Questions
========
id
type   (choose, complete, true or false, match)
content

Answers
=======
id
question_id
content. content
isCorrect
```

However, by researching current successful applications such as quizlet, I found that they take Term&Definition approach by placing the term and definition in one table, and questions and exams are created from this table in its various forms, as follows:

```
terms
=========
id
term
definition
```

First, I want to know which of the two approach is better in the application in terms of diversity and expansion.
Secondly, in Term&Definition approach, for example, if I create a question with four choices from a table filled with thousands of terms and definitions, how do I guarantee that these four choices for this question are homogeneous and close in correct because the choices are added randomly every time the question is created

Comment: Hi - as this forum requires you to limit yourself to one question, which of your two questions do you want to ask? Also “better” is a subjective term which invites opinions - and opinion-based questions are also not permitted. So what is your definition of “better” in this use case? Finally, your description of term/definition seems to imply that the questions are being generated at runtime rather than being predefined. So these are two fundamentally different types of application - so this doesn’t seem to be the sort of technical/coding question this forum could answer